# How to stop a web page from loading any page elements further? Escape key not enough?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

There was a time when hitting the escape key while a web page was loading, stopped the web page elements from loading further in the browser. If I got the info I wanted from a web page, what is the simplest way to prevent it from loading further?

There are certain sites that load several megabytes of image & video ads. I understand some of these are loaded dynamically through AJAX. Irrespective of whether the content is ads or anything else, is there a way to make the browser stop from loading a page further?

Comment: Close the page, disconnect your internet, disable script execution (e.g. NoScript) and use an AdBlocker and click the cancel button. Are you only using Chrome?

Comment: I see this behavior with popular browsers like Chrome, Firefox. Closing the page & disconnecting internet are extremes. When did the escape key get sidelined? Have the browser makers done it on purpose? Is there a way to force the escape key to do its job?

Comment: The escape key does work (in Firefox) it would depend on what is actually happening. If you wait for the whole page to load any number of scripts might be running and you would need to cancel those requests. Depending on how they happen you are able to do that with escape (for each request) or not as they are invisible to you.